# Error in creating a custom run instances policy

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am new to IAM in AWS. I have created a policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:DescribeImages",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:109027:instance/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:10927:image/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:109027:security-group/Test_hin",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:109027:subnet/subnet-b",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:109527:key-pair/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:10903527:network-interface/vpc-e4",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:107:volume/*"
       ]
     }
   ]
}
```

whenever I am trying to launch an instance using console, It gives me an error that i am not authorized to perform this action.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The describe actions have to be configured separately with `"*"` as the resource.

Comment: Try with `"Action": "ec2:Describe*"` first and see how that goes.

Comment: then it shows me very subnet every image . everything no restriction

Comment: You can limit the image with the "run instances" policy declaration, so I don't think you have much to worry about here.

Comment: You can let someone see all the options, but they can only really do something with it when they click "Run instance" at the end ... and you can control that part with the `ec2:RunInstances` restrictions.

Comment: i dont want to limit the image i want user to create the instance in a particular subnet

Comment: image, subnet, etc. doesn't matter .. it's your policy after all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49448/discussion-between-user3086014-and-jack)

Comment: sirwhen i am using `"Action": ["ec2:Describe*"],` i get error an error occured fetching the data

Comment: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message. even when i write descirbe *

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `key pair` and the `network interface` resources (Looks like you are trying to launch into a VPC). Also, allow the volume resources.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
       "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:acct:instance/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:acct:image/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:acct:security-group/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:acct:subnet/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:acct:key-pair/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:acct:network-interface/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:acct:volume/*"
       ]
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: yeah i am lanching the instances in a vpc.

Comment: and i m trying to launch the instance on console not on CLI

Comment: when i am selecting the ami it gives an error you are not authorized to perform the operation!!!

Comment: Shouldn't matter whether it's console or CLI

Comment: @Rico It does matter, because he's not specifying `describeXYZ` permissions.

Comment: how to specify that sir

Comment: @Jack not sure I understand, I believe describeXYZ works whether you use it from the command line or the console. In essence the console and the CLI (whatever flavor: ruby, Python, Java, etc) are using the same back end API.

Comment: @Rico Indeed they do, but what I'm saying is that those describe actions are probably not given so the console will give an error for the user to which the policy is attached even though the CLI can launch an image without an issue.

Comment: Try with this `"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:acct:subnet/*",` I've edited the answer

Comment: what is this volume..i dont want to specify this

Comment: I only want that user should launch an instance in a specific subnet

Comment: You need the volume to launch EBS backed instances, which are the ones that most people use. If you need a specific subnet specify: `"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:acct:subnet/<subnet-id>",`

Comment: Please see the screen shot of the error in question

Comment: please see my policy in the question

Comment: Please rico whats wrong with the policy .. i cant understand

Comment: Those don't look like account ids ? The account ids usually 12 numbers and they all have to be same on your policy. For example in this statement: `"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:1527:instance/*"` 1527 doesn't look like an account id

Comment: no the acct id and vpc i cant write on the post but they are valid

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49116/discussion-between-user3086014-and-rico)